# Permission denied to access /var/run/docker.sock mounted in a OpenShift container

Tags: docker, permissions, openshift, selinux

## Objective

Know how to trouble shoot and what knowledge is required to trouble shoot permission issues of Docker container accessing host files.

### Problem

Access to /var/run/docker.sock mounted inside a OpenShift container via hostPath causes permission denied. The issue does not happen if the same container is deployed to K8S 1.9.x, hence it is OpenShift specific issue.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-4-62 ~]$ ls -laZ /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw----. root docker system_u:object_r:container_var_run_t:s0 /var/run/docker.sock

[ec2-user@ip-10-0-4-62 ~]$ docker exec 9d0c6763d855 ls -laZ /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw----. 1 root 1002 system_u:object_r:container_var_run_t:s0 0 Jan 16 09:54 /var/run/docker.sock
```

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1244634 says svirt_sandbox_file_t SELinux label is required for RHEL, so changed the label.

```
$ chcon -Rt container_runtime_t docker.sock 
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-4-62 ~]$ ls -aZ /var/run/docker.sock 
srw-rw----. root docker system_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t:s0 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Redeploy the container but still permission denied.

```
$ docker exec -it 9d0c6763d855 curl -ivs --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/version
*   Trying /var/run/docker.sock...
* Immediate connect fail for /var/run/docker.sock: Permission denied
* Closing connection 0
```

OpenShift by default does not allow hostPath so it was addressed.

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user privileged system:serviceaccount:{{ DATADOG_NAMESPACE }}:{{ DATADOG_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}
```

I suppose SELinux or OpenShift SCC or other container/docker permission is causing this but need a clue how to find the cause.

Comment: There is a default settings which prohibit containers to run as root in OpenShift. To use the docker socker you need root permissions. Maybe allow your container to run as root will help? (it's some time ago I touched this so don't shoot me if I'm wrong): `oadm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default`

Comment: @lvthillo thanks for the comment.  With privileged: true, I can run the pod as root and avoid the issue, but it is not allowed. Need to find a way to work-around the SELinux and manage pod permission.

Answer (score 1):

Openshift requires special permissions for in order to allow pods to use volumes in nodes.

Do the following:

1. Create standard security-context yaml:

   ```
   kind: SecurityContextConstraints
   apiVersion: v1
   metadata:
     name: scc-hostpath
   allowPrivilegedContainer: true
   runAsUser:
     type: RunAsAny
   seLinuxContext:
     type: RunAsAny
   fsGroup:
     type: RunAsAny
   supplementalGroups:
     type: RunAsAny
   users:
   - my-admin-user
   groups:
   - my-admin-group

   oc create -f scc-hostpath.yam
   ```
2. Add the "allowHostDirVolumePlugin" privilege to this security-context:

   ```
   oc patch scc scc-hostpath -p '{"allowHostDirVolumePlugin": true}'
   ```
3. Associate the pod's service account with the above security context

   ```
   oc adm policy add-scc-to-user scc-hostpath system:serviceaccount:<service_account_name>
   ```