# How to allow Jenkins to call docker out of the container

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, openshift

I have locally installed OpenShift platform. Jenkins has been deployed there as a dockerized application. I need to call Docker during Jenkins job executing to perform some base Docker operations: build, push, pull.

Unfortunately Docker is not reachable out of the Jenkins container.

```
$ oc exec -it jenkins-1-cdjdx -- /bin/bash
$ docker
bash: docker: command not found
```

As far as I understood I have to install the [Docker plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) and perform a new cloud item for Jenkins global settings. So I would try to describe Docker as a new cloud item but unfortunately I don't know how to define a Docker Host URI and a port.

Answer (score 0):

Docker plugin will not install docker to the container, it will just add docker support to Jenkins.

You need to install docker client inside a Jenkins container. I don't know which image you use, but hope you will find a right way of how to do it.

Than, you have 2 ways of how to make it works:

1. Attach docker socket from a host machine to your container. It means, you need to mount hosts' /var/run/docker.sock to the same path in the container. In OpenShift you also can use `exposeDockerSocket` option for a [build strategy](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/dev_guide/builds/build_strategies.html), but I don't think you use that feature here. But if you run it as a general pod, you need to mount it using "hostPath" volume. Also, I think you will need to modify security policy, check [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48337140/permission-denied-to-access-var-run-docker-sock-mounted-in-a-openshift-containe) question.
2. Run independent Docker right in your container, that mode named Docker-in-Docker. You can google it, but I think the first option is better in your case.